# How do you convert CString and std::string std::wstring to each other?

Tags: c++, mfc, c-strings, stdstring

`CString` is quite handy, while `std::string` is more compatible with STL container. I am using `hash_map`. However, `hash_map` does not support `CString`s as keys, so I want to convert the `CString` into a `std::string`.

Writing a `CString` hash function seems to take a lot of time.

```
CString -----> std::string
```

How can I do this?

```
std::string -----> CString:

inline CString toCString(std::string const& str)
{
    return CString(str.c_str()); 
}
```

Am I right?

---

**EDIT:**

Here are more questions:

How can I convert from `wstring` to `CString` and vice versa?

```
// wstring -> CString
std::wstring src;
CString result(src.c_str());

// CString -> wstring
CString src;
std::wstring des(src.GetString());
```

Is there any problem with this?

Additionally, how can I convert from `std::wstring` to `std::string` and vice versa?

Comment: I wouldn't do this... Using two different strings types is bad enough, but having to convert every time you do something with a map? Sounds terrible. Just be consistent and use std::string. If for some reason you really think CString is better, then define an hash function for it so your hash_map can use it, this is far better than doubling the confusing in your code.

Comment: Actually, If all code is written by myself it will be consistent, but there are some opensourced project such as freeimage sqlite used. I can not modify there code.

Comment: I answered a contemporary answer (VS2017 MFC ...Since VS2012)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

According to [CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-231155.html):

`CString` to `std::string`:

```
CString cs("Hello");
std::string s((LPCTSTR)cs);
```

**BUT:** `std::string` cannot always construct from a `LPCTSTR`. i.e. the code will fail for UNICODE builds.

As `std::string` can construct only from `LPSTR` / `LPCSTR`, a programmer who uses VC++ 7.x or better can utilize conversion classes such as `CT2CA` as an intermediary.

```
CString cs ("Hello");
// Convert a TCHAR string to a LPCSTR
CT2CA pszConvertedAnsiString (cs);
// construct a std::string using the LPCSTR input
std::string strStd (pszConvertedAnsiString);
```

[`std::string` to `CString`](http://cstrings.blogspot.com/2006/08/how-to-convert-from-stdstring-to.html): (From [Visual Studio's CString FAQs...](http://cstrings.blogspot.com/2006/08/how-to-convert-from-stdstring-to.html))

```
std::string s("Hello");
CString cs(s.c_str());
```

`CStringT` can construct from both character or wide-character strings. i.e. It can convert from `char*` (i.e. `LPSTR`) or from `wchar_t*` (`LPWSTR`).

In other words, char-specialization (of `CStringT`) i.e. `CStringA`, `wchar_t`-specilization `CStringW`, and `TCHAR`-specialization `CString` can be constructed from either `char` or wide-character, <del>null terminated (null-termination is very important here)</del> string sources.
Althoug [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) amends the "null-termination" part [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258050/how-to-convert-cstring-and-stdstring-stdwstring-to-each-other/258052?noredirect=1#comment29168168_258052):

> **NUL-termination is not required**.
>   `CStringT` has conversion constructors that take an explicit length argument. This also means that you can construct `CStringT` objects from `std::string` objects with embedded `NUL` characters.

Comment: Errr... you are welcome :) Thanks to Siddhartha Rao for the detailed explanations.

Comment: The last paragraph is not entirely correct. `NUL`-termination is not required. [`CStringT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cws1zdt8.aspx) has conversion constructors that take an explicit length argument. This also means that you can construct `CStringT` objects from `std::string` objects with embedded `NUL` characters.

Comment: @IInspectable good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The But statement was really helpful to me :D

Comment: This answer is very useful and explanatory, but [OJ's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/258217/1995714) is a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 37):

Solve that by using `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` instead of `std::string` and it should work fine regardless of your character setting.

Comment: I like to typedef that for convenience and familiarity: `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring`

Answer (score 6):

If you want something more C++-like, this is what I use.  Although it depends on Boost, that's just for exceptions.  You can easily remove those leaving it to depend only on the STL and the `WideCharToMultiByte()` Win32 API call.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <exception>

#include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>
#include <boost/integer_traits.hpp>

/**
 * Convert a Windows wide string to a UTF-8 (multi-byte) string.
 */
std::string WideStringToUtf8String(const std::wstring& wide)
{
    if (wide.size() > boost::integer_traits<int>::const_max)
        throw std::length_error(
            "Wide string cannot be more than INT_MAX characters long.");
    if (wide.size() == 0)
        return "";

    // Calculate necessary buffer size
    int len = ::WideCharToMultiByte(
        CP_UTF8, 0, wide.c_str(), static_cast<int>(wide.size()), 
        NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Perform actual conversion
    if (len > 0)
    {
        std::vector<char> buffer(len);
        len = ::WideCharToMultiByte(
            CP_UTF8, 0, wide.c_str(), static_cast<int>(wide.size()),
            &buffer[0], static_cast<int>(buffer.size()), NULL, NULL);
        if (len > 0)
        {
            assert(len == static_cast<int>(buffer.size()));
            return std::string(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
        }
    }

    throw boost::system::system_error(
        ::GetLastError(), boost::system::system_category);
}
```

Comment: The [CW2AEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/cw2aex-class) class does all that for you already.

Comment: `CString cstr1("Hello Unicode!");`
`CW2AEX<128> stdstr1((LPCTSTR)cstr1);`

Thank to @IInspectable

Answer (score 5):

> Is there **any** problem?

There are several issues:

- `CString` is a template specialization of [CStringT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class). Depending on the *BaseType* describing the character type, there are two concrete specializations: `CStringA` (using `char`) and `CStringW` (using `wchar_t`).
- While `wchar_t` on Windows is ubiquitously used to store UTF-16 encoded code units, using `char` is ambiguous. The latter commonly stores ANSI encoded characters, but can also store ASCII, UTF-8, or even binary data.
- We don't know the character encoding (or even character type) of `CString` (which is controlled through the `_UNICODE` preprocessor symbol), making the question ambiguous. We also don't know the desired character encoding of `std::string`.
- Converting between Unicode and ANSI is inherently lossy: ANSI encoding can only represent a subset of the Unicode character set.

To address these issues, I'm going to assume that `wchar_t` will store UTF-16 encoded code units, and `char` will hold UTF-8 octet sequences. That's the only reasonable choice you can make to ensure that source and destination strings retain the same information, without limiting the solution to a subset of the source or destination domains.

The following implementations convert between `CStringA`/`CStringW` and `std::wstring`/`std::string` mapping from UTF-8 to UTF-16 and vice versa:

```
#include <string>
#include <atlconv.h>

std::string to_utf8(CStringW const& src_utf16)
{
    return { CW2A(src_utf16.GetString(), CP_UTF8).m_psz };
}

std::wstring to_utf16(CStringA const& src_utf8)
{
    return { CA2W(src_utf8.GetString(), CP_UTF8).m_psz };
}
```

The remaining two functions construct C++ string objects from MFC strings, leaving the encoding unchanged. Note that while the previous functions cannot cope with embedded NUL characters, these functions are immune to that.

```
#include <string>
#include <atlconv.h>

std::string to_std_string(CStringA const& src)
{
    return { src.GetString(), src.GetString() + src.GetLength() };
}

std::wstring to_std_wstring(CStringW const& src)
{
    return { src.GetString(), src.GetString() + src.GetLength() };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is more efficient to convert `CString` to `std::string` using the conversion where the length is specified.

```
CString someStr("Hello how are you");
std::string std(someStr, someStr.GetLength());
```

In a tight loop, this makes a significant performance improvement.

Comment: I got an error using this: `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CString' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &'`

Comment: which version of std library you are using --- boost or C++ 11?

Comment: I got an error saying 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::basic_string: none of the 16 overloads could convert all the argument types'. on Visual Studio 2022 with language version set to C++ 20.

Answer (score 3):

(Since VS2012 ...and at least until VS2017 v15.8.1)

Since it's a MFC project & CString is a MFC class, MS provides a Technical Note [TN059: Using MFC MBCS/Unicode Conversion Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/805c56f8.aspx) and Generic Conversion Macros:

```
A2CW      (LPCSTR)  -> (LPCWSTR)  
A2W       (LPCSTR)  -> (LPWSTR)  
W2CA      (LPCWSTR) -> (LPCSTR)  
W2A       (LPCWSTR) -> (LPSTR)
```

Use:

```
void Example() // ** UNICODE case **
{
    USES_CONVERSION; // (1)

    // CString to std::string / std::wstring
    CString strMfc{ "Test" }; // strMfc = L"Test"
    std::string strStd = W2A(strMfc); // ** Conversion Macro: strStd = "Test" **
    std::wstring wstrStd = strMfc.GetString(); // wsrStd = L"Test"

    // std::string to CString / std::wstring
    strStd = "Test 2";
    strMfc = strStd.c_str(); // strMfc = L"Test 2"
    wstrStd = A2W(strStd.c_str()); // ** Conversion Macro: wstrStd = L"Test 2" **

    // std::wstring to CString / std::string 
    wstrStd = L"Test 3";
    strMfc = wstrStd.c_str(); // strMfc = L"Test 3"
    strStd = W2A(wstrStd.c_str()); // ** Conversion Macro: strStd = "Test 3" **
}
```

--

Footnotes:

(1) In order to for the conversion-macros to have space to store the temporary length, it is necessary to declare a local variable called `_convert` that does this in each function that uses the conversion macros. This is done by invoking the `USES_CONVERSION` macro. In VS2017 MFC code (atlconv.h) it looks like this:

```
#ifndef _DEBUG
    #define USES_CONVERSION int _convert; (_convert); UINT _acp = ATL::_AtlGetConversionACP() /*CP_THREAD_ACP*/; (_acp); LPCWSTR _lpw; (_lpw); LPCSTR _lpa; (_lpa)
#else
    #define USES_CONVERSION int _convert = 0; (_convert); UINT _acp = ATL::_AtlGetConversionACP() /*CP_THREAD_ACP*/; (_acp); LPCWSTR _lpw = NULL; (_lpw); LPCSTR _lpa = NULL; (_lpa)
#endif
```

Comment: `USES_CONVERSION` is not required when using ATL 7.0 [string conversion macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx). ATL 7.0 shipped with Visual Studio 2003.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine:

```
//Convert CString to std::string
inline std::string to_string(const CString& cst)
{
    return CT2A(cst.GetString());
}
```

Comment: this will not work well for Japanese characters

Answer (score 2):

From this post (Thank you [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) )

[Convert CString to string (VC6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954399/convert-cstring-to-string-vc6)

I have tested this and it works fine.

```
std::string Utils::CString2String(const CString& cString) 
{
    std::string strStd;

    for (int i = 0;  i < cString.GetLength();  ++i)
    {
        if (cString[i] <= 0x7f)
            strStd.append(1, static_cast<char>(cString[i]));
        else
            strStd.append(1, '?');
    }

    return strStd;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to convert `CString to std::string`. You can use this format.

```
std::string sText(CW2A(CSText.GetString(), CP_UTF8 ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your first answer. Please use code highlighting:

To convert `CString` to `std::string` you can use this:

`std::string sText(CW2A(CSText.GetString(), CP_UTF8 ));`.

Answer (score 2):

`CString` has method, `GetString()`, that returns an `LPCWSTR` type if you are using Unicode, or `LPCSTR` otherwise.

In the Unicode case, you must pass it through a `wstring`:

```
CString cs("Hello");
wstring ws = wstring(cs.GetString());
string s = string(ws.begin(), ws.end());
```

Else you can simply convert the string directly:

```
CString cs("Hello");
string s = string(cs.GetString());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a follow up to Sal's answer, where he/she provided the solution:

```
CString someStr("Hello how are you");
std::string std(somStr, someStr.GetLength());
```

This is useful also when converting a non-typical C-String to a std::string

A use case for me was having a pre-allocated char array (like C-String), but it's not NUL terminated. (i.e. SHA digest).
The above syntax allows me to specify the length of the SHA digest of the char array so that std::string doesn't have to look for the terminating NUL char, which may or may not be there.

Such as:

```
unsigned char hashResult[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];    
auto value = std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>hashResult, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
```

Comment: Perhaps, it would be better if you edited Sal's answer with your amendment attached or commented on Sal's answer?

Comment: I tried... but stackoverflow hasn't granted me the ability to do and edit.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting approach is to cast `CString` to `CStringA` inside a `string` constructor. Unlike `std::string s((LPCTSTR)cs);` this will work even if `_UNICODE` is defined. However, if that is the case, this will perform conversion from Unicode to ANSI, so it is unsafe for higher Unicode values beyond the ASCII character set. Such conversion is subject to the `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` preprocessor definition. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx

```
        CString s1("SomeString");
        string s2((CStringA)s1);
```

Comment: That's not a cast. It's a conversion. `CString` has conversion constructors, using the calling thread's current locale. The conversion is lossy, and you may window up with a string that no longer represents the source. Yes, it's easy, convenient. But also wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable `(CStringA)s1` is a cast in the sense that it's an explicit conversion. Is that the part you consider wrong here? If this works in specific use cases, which it does, then by definition it cannot be wrong for those use cases. If it is easy and convenient, then all the better. So you are saying that casting CString to CStringA is not always reliable because of locale correct? I specifically asked "why not..." suspecting as much, and I'm interested if you can provide details. I'll update accordingly, but would you call this approach wrong so long as the limitations are understood?

Comment: Locale is *one* limitation. The more fatal one being, that ANSI encoding cannot represent all code points available in the Unicode specification. That conversion is lossy. You will inevitably lose information. Defining the `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` preprocessor symbol is the safe option: It will cause this proposed solution to fail to compile. This solution isn't even safe if all limitations are understood, as there is no way to enforce the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CT2CA**

```
CString datasetPath;
CT2CA st(datasetPath);
string dataset(st);
```

Answer (score 0):

All other answers didn't quite address what I was looking for which was to convert `CString` on the fly as opposed to store the result in a variable.

The solution is similar to above but we need one more step to instantiate a nameless object. I am illustrating with an example. Here is my function which needs `std::string` but I have `CString`.

```
void CStringsPlayDlg::writeLog(const std::string &text)
{
    std::string filename = "c:\\test\\test.txt";

    std::ofstream log_file(filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);

    log_file << text << std::endl;
}
```

How to call it when you have a `CString`?

```
std::string firstName = "First";
CString lastName = _T("Last");

writeLog( firstName + ", " + std::string( CT2A( lastName ) ) );
```

Note that the last line is not a direct typecast but we are creating a nameless `std::string` object and supply the `CString` via its constructor.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to convert easily between other strings types, perhaps the [`_bstr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6(VS.71).aspx) class would be more appropriate? It supports converstion between `char`, `wchar_t` and `BSTR`.

Comment: -1 `CString` already does all the conversions you name. And it did 3 years ago as well. No point in suggesting a type that is meant for use in COM environments.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me:

```
std::wstring CStringToWString(const CString& s)
{
    std::string s2;
    s2 = std::string((LPCTSTR)s);
    return std::wstring(s2.begin(),s2.end());
}

CString WStringToCString(std::wstring s)
{
    std::string s2;
    s2 = std::string(s.begin(),s.end());
    return s2.c_str();
}
```

Comment: Works, until it fails. `WStringToCString` will fail for any non-ASCII character in the source string. `CStringToWString` will fail for any non-ASCII character as well, producing invalid UTF-16 code units. I understand that this solution keeps popping up every now and again, but it has always been wrong, and it will continue to be wrong.