# Convert CString to std::wstring

Tags: c++, string, wstring

How can I convert from `CString` to `std::wstring`?

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258050/how-to-convert-cstring-and-stdstring-stdwstring-to-each-other

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859304/convert-cstring-to-const-char

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To convert `CString` to `std::wstring`:

```
CString hi("Hi");
std::wstring hi2(hi);
```

And to go the other way, use `c_str()`:

```
std::wstring hi(L"Hi");
CString hi2(hi.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work as `CString` has `operator LPCTSTR()` defined:

```
CString s;
std::wstring s1 = s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
std::wstring strString((LPCTSTR)strCString);
```

Comment: Why use a C cast for that? A fellow-worker of mine once was in the position that he had to find explicit casts, as some of them didn't work on the platform he needed to port a 4MLoC project to. He praised everyone who used C++' explicit casts (you can grep for them) and fought hard to ban all C-style casts, since they were so hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

```
CString s = _T("Привет");
USES_CONVERSION;
std::wstring ws(A2W((LPCTSTR)s));
```