# Convert String^ to wstring C++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

As this is my first post (and it's a question :D ) I have to say this website is amazing and very helpful. Thank You for making it.
So, here is my problem... I'm trying to convert String^ to wstring, searching already 3 days but cannot find anything about that..
I'm writing a program that creates a desktop shortcut of the file user selects. I use FolderBrowserDialog^ so that users can select the path, and it returns String^, and I use IShellLink to create the shortcut, which works with LPCWSTR. So I need to convert String^ to LPCWSTR, and I don't know how to, but I can convert wstring to LPCWSTR, so if I could do String^ to wstring, would be great))
Thank you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1ae6tz5.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::wstring new_wstring(c_string)`
where new_wstring is the name of your new wstring, and c_string is the name of your String:
[Convert CString to std::wstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041241/convert-cstring-to-stdwstring)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much. I would like to post the code so that everyone can see the final result. Here is what i did:

```
String^ str1 = "Your Text";
char* str2 = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str1);
CString target = str2;
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)str2);
CString str3 = CString(str2);
std::wstring new_wstring(str3);
```