# How to convert string with double high/wide characters to normal string [VC++6]

Tags: c++, string

My application typically recieves a string in the following format:
   "     Item   $5.69   "

Some contants I always expect:
 - the LENGHT always 20 characters
 - the start index of the text always [5]
 - and most importantly the index of the DECIMAL for the price always [14]
In order to identify this string correctly I validate all the expected contants listed above ....

Some of my clients have now started sending the string with Doube-High / Double-Wide values (pair of characters which represent a single readable character) similar to the following:
   "     Item   $x80x90.x81x91x82x92   "

For testing I simply scan the string character-by-character, compare char[i] and char[i+1] and replace these pairs with their corresponding single character when a match is found (works fine) as follows:

[Code]

```
for (int i=0; i < sData.length(); i++)
{
   char ch = sData[i] & 0xFF;
   char ch2 = sData[i+1] & 0xFF;

   if (ch == '\x80' && ch2 == '\x90')
      zData.replace("\x80\x90", "0");
   else if (ch == '\x81' && ch2 == '\x91')
      zData.replace("\x81\x91", "1");
   else if (ch == '\x82' && ch2 == '\x92')
      zData.replace("\x82\x92", "2");
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

[/Code]

But the result is something like this:
"     Item  $5.69 "

Notice how this no longer matches my expectation: the lenght is now 17 (instead of 20) due to the 3 conversions and the decimal is now at index 13 (instead of 14) due to the conversion of the "5" before the decimal point.

Ideally I would like to convert the string to a normal readable format keeping the constants (length, index of text, index of decimal) at the same place (so the rest of my application is re-usable) ... or any other suggestion (I'm pretty much stuck with this)... Is there a STANDARD way of dealing with these type of characters?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while now ...

Thanks,

Comment: search for "convert wide char to char".  if you do find a solution please post it. if no one finds a solution for a few days, I will try to write up something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258050/how-to-convert-cstring-and-stdstring-stdwstring-to-each-other

Comment: Won't using WideCharToMultiByte still change the constants (like the overall string size, location of the decimal, etc...)?

Comment: What the heck kinda code is that?  Are they treating you like a printer or something?  It is not Unicode.

Comment: Maybe, my assumption is that this is actually some kind of receipt data ... But if it is not unicode ... then what is it?

Comment: From what I can see it is double-high / double-wide VDisplay characters provided by QVS TSNT application ... can't really find anything more then that ...

Answer (score 1):

You need Unicode Normal Form. [This Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374126(VS.85).aspx?ppud=4) will help you, in spite of being about VS8. NormalizeString API is independent of the version of Visual Studio in use.