# Convert CString to string (VC6)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I want to convert CString to string. (Yup. I know what am I doing. I know the returned string will be incorrect, if CString value range is outside ANSI, but That's Is OK!)

The following code will work under VC2008.

```
std::string Utils::CString2String(const CString& cString) 
{
    // Convert a TCHAR string to a LPCSTR
    CT2CA pszConvertedAnsiString (cString);

    // construct a std::string using the LPCSTR input
    std::string strStd (pszConvertedAnsiString);

    return strStd;
}
```

But VC6 doesn't have CT2CA macro. How I can make the code to work as well in both VC6 and VC2008?

Comment: Are you compiling Unicode? That is, does CString contain Unicode characters? Also, why oh **why** are you using VC6? It's twelve years old!!

Comment: We compile both in Unicode and Multi-byte. Hey! Ever heard about "Huge Legacy Code Base"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft says that [CT2CA replaces T2CA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx), so try the latter and see if that works.

Comment: USES_CONVERSION; std::string str = T2CA((LPCTSTR)cString));

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't care about characters outside the ANSI range, brute force would work.

```
std::string Utils::CString2String(const CString& cString) 
{
    std::string strStd;

    for (int i = 0;  i < cString.GetLength();  ++i)
    {
        if (cString[i] <= 0x7f)
            strStd.append(1, static_cast<char>(cString[i]));
        else
            strStd.append(1, '?');
    }

    return strStd;
}
```