# Newbie to pointers

Tags: c++

I need to put `cs` value inside the bracket for the object `client`. I have already handle the `cs` variable like this:

```
CString cs (bar_->GetHostName());
```

But still fail to put the value inside this below code:

```
WinHttpClient client(/* dont know what value to put here */);   
client.SendHttpRequest();
```

Error message:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'WinHttpClient::WinHttpClient(const std::wstring &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [15]' to 'const std::wstring &' c:\test.cpp
```

edit :

```
   CString cs (bar_->GetHostName());
   WinHttpClient client(/*??*/);
   client.SendHttpRequest();
   wstring httpResponseHeader = client.GetHttpResponseHeader();
   wstring httpResponse = client.GetHttpResponse();
   writeToStorage(httpResponse.c_str());
```

My function `writeToStorage` suppose to write something to a textfile. It seems, overwriting the file with no strings in it.. I dont know why :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using MFC's `CString` and you want to pass `cs` to the `WinHttpClient`.

Here is how you do it:

```
CString cs (bar_->GetHostName());
std::string s((LPCTSTR)cs);
WinHttpClient client(s);   
client.SendHttpRequest();
```

If WinHttpClient has an overloaded constructor that accepts wchar*, then you can do it like this:

```
CString cs (bar_->GetHostName());
WinHttpClient client(cs);   
client.SendHttpRequest();
```

However, if you want to pass plain text as mentioned in some other answers, then do this:

```
WinHttpClient client(_T("Text"));   
client.SendHttpRequest();
```

In Visual C++, using `_T` is a better option than using `L`

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a `std::wstring`.

This question explains the conversions: [How to convert CString and ::std::string  ::std::wstring to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258050/how-to-convert-cstring-and-stdstring-stdwstring-to-each-other)

Answer (score 0):

Write `WinHttpClient client(L"text");` instead of `WinHttpClient client("text");`

Answer (score -1):

Abyx is right. You should to write L before the string. But it works only with constant strings. L is a macros that converts char[] to wchar_t[] - Unicode char array. For dynamic converting you have to use [MultiByteToWideChar (...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202786.aspx) function.

Comment: "L" isn't a macros, it's a part of wide string literal.