# Convert from ATL::CString to string in C++

Tags: c++, string, cstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert CString and ::std::string  ::std::wstring to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258050/how-to-convert-cstring-and-stdstring-stdwstring-to-each-other)

Ok, I know my question may be trivial, but I have not yet found how I can convert an ATL::Cstring to a basic string. I have tried the "converting from CString example" of the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631%28v=vs.80%29.aspx but it does not work. Any due indication?

Answer (score 7):

This should work -

```
CStringA cstr1("Hello");
std::string str1(cstr1);
```

OR

```
CStringW cstr2(L"Hello");
std::wstring str2(cstr2);
```

`CString` is a macro that may be converted to `CStringA` or `CStringW` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not.

Assigning `CStringA` to `std::wstring` and `CStringW` to `std::string` will not work, which is probably what is happening for you.