# Cannot figure out how to convert this std::string to a CString

Tags: c++, string, casting, mfc, type-conversion

I am writing an MFC program in Visual Studio 10 and I need to convert an std::string to a CString so that I can use it as a parameter for dialog controls.

I have tried every method that I can think of/find, including:

(note: all of these have an already filled std::string, named `str`.)

```
CString c = str.c_str();
```

---

```
CString c;
c.Format(_T("%s"),str);
```

---

```
CString c = (CString)str; //desperate attempt, I know....
```

---

```
CString c;
c.Format(L"%s", str);
```

---

Can someone help me figure out how to get this conversion done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258050/how-to-convert-cstring-and-stdstring-stdwstring-to-each-other?rq=1

Comment: Your first one should work.