# C++ File Write includes the memory address of the string instead of the contents

Tags: c++, string, pointers, mfc, filestreams

All,
I'm still learning C++ but I have an issue in a project I'm tinkering with that I'm curious about. I've noticed that when I try to print  the contents of a string that is a member of a class, I get the memory address instead of the contents.  I understand that this is because the item is a pointer, but what I"m confused about is that I am using the `->` operator to deference it.

Why can I evaluate the class member in an if statement using the `->` operator to dereference it but when printing to a file string in the same manner I get the memory address instead?

An example is below:

Lets say I have a class called pClass with a member called `m_strEmployeeName`. As a side note (I don't know if it matters), the `m_strEmployeeName` value is `CString` rather than `std::string`, so there could be some unknown conversion issue possibly as well.

If I used the following simple code, I get a memory address.

```
std::ofstream file("testfile.text");
file << pClass->m_strEmployeeName;
file.close();
```

I get the same behavior with the following dereferencing method (which I would expect since -> is the same thing).

```
std::ofstream file("testfile.text");
file << (*pClass).m_strEmployeeName;
file.close();
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Problem is `CString` not how you refer that member. Just create a variable of type `CString` and try to print it.

Comment: Just to make sure, you know you are dereferencing `pClass`, not `m_strEmployeeName`, right? Cause in the sentence `I understand that this is because the item is a pointer, but what I"m confused about is that I am using the -> operator to deference it.` you seem to imply otherwise.

Comment: I've added the `MFC` tag, since you are using `CString`. `CString` is not part of the standard C++ library and the iostreams knows nothing of it (hence the address being printed). ebyrob's answer will work if you need to stick with `CString`.

Comment: Check the docs for `CString` for the correct way to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your `CString` class is actualy `CStringW` class wich contain `wchar_t` strings so `std::ofstream` not contain `operator >>` overload that support `wchar_t*` strings. To print `CStringW` class objects you may use this type of stream `std::wofstream` it recognize `wchar_t*` strings properly and output will be right.

```
std::wofstream file("testfile.text");
file << pClass->m_strEmployeeName;
file.close();
```

You may also create your program in multibyte character support. It can be specified in your project settings. But I suggest you to stay with UNICODE.

Comment: Does this create an ASCII (UTF-8) or UNICODE (UTF-16) file as output?

Comment: MFC no longer supports MBCS (and the question is tagged with MFC).

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein: Actualy it supports but it must be downloaded separately from Microsoft site.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting `CString` to a `char` pointer:

```
file << (LPCTSTR)pClass->m_strEmployeeName;
```

see: [How to convert CString and ::std::string  ::std::wstring to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258050/how-to-convert-cstring-and-stdstring-stdwstring-to-each-other)

Note: This will only work if you have TCHAR defined as 8 bits.  If you're using 16-bit UNICODE TCHAR, you'd have one more conversion.

Here is one way of doing the `TCHAR` conversion:

```
char c_str[1000];
size_t ret;    
wcstombs_s(
   &ret,
   c_str,
   sizeof(c_str),
   (LPCTSTR)pClass->m_strEmployeeName,
   pClass->m_strEmployeeName.GetLength()
);

std::ofstream file("testfile.text");
file << c_str;
file.close();
```

Useful if you need 8-bit ASCII file but have a UNICODE `CString` to work with.

Comment: I would recommend using `std::string` instead rather than convert.

Comment: @Slava agreed, but in case there's a good reason to use `CString` this will work.

Comment: Output will remain same, because `UNICODE` is defined so `LPCTSTR` will be `LPCWSTR` and it is `const wchar_t*`, `T` letter means `TCHAR` and WHEN `UNICODE` is defined it will be `WCHAR` alse it is `CHAR`.