# How can I convert CString to WCHAR* and std::string to WCHAR* in C++, not wchar_t*

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mfc, wchar

I want to convert `CString` to `WCHAR*` or `std::string` to `WCHAR*` in Visual Studio C++ MFC Application. I found in stackoverflow that it only has the solution for convert to `wchar_t*`.

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: `WCHAR` is used in Windows as an alias for `wchar_t`. You might be interested in studying [this common types for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) reference.

Comment: If you are asking how to convert from 8bit strings to 16bit strings then you can use CA2WEX from ATL : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ca2wex-class?view=msvc-170

Comment: `CString` is a typedef that either aliases `CStringA` or `CStringW`. An answer to this question would be different for either case.

Answer (score 0):

When you use CString, you could access the CW2A ATL macro,which converts CString to string.

```
CString theCStr;
std::string STDStr( CW2A( theCStr.GetString(), CP_UTF8 ) );
```

Or refer to this [document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258050/how-do-you-convert-cstring-and-stdstring-stdwstring-to-each-other).

Comment: The question is asking how to convert to `WCHAR*`. `CW2A` will not do that. And it's the wrong macro, too. If you're using a `CString` (as opposed to a `CStringW`), the compatible conversion macro is called `CT2A`.

Comment: This [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46ef3191-aff1-4532-9953-42ddc313e09d/convert-a-cstring-to-wchar?forum=vssmartdevicesnative) explains how to convert cstring to wchar*.

Comment: That entry suffers from the exact same inconsistency as this proposed answer. If you're using the ambient character set, you have to use it **consistently**. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/258050/1889329) is far more useful. And it's on-site, too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `CString` class can do such conversion:

```
CStringA a = "ANSI";
CStringW w(a);
```

Comment: I believe this doesn't address the question. As I read it, the OP needs to convert a `CString` to a `WCHAR*`, but only found solutions that would convert to `wchar_t*`. Apparently, they aren't realizing that `WCHAR*` and `wchar_t*` are the same thing on Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable possibly; I was just trying to show a way without using error-prone macros.

Comment: Sure, except, this has pitfalls just as well. "ANSI" is only half of a character encoding. The other half is missing (and implied, and possibly wrong).